# Find Largest Values in Column and Count in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to find the largest values of the column **Values** which are marked by the number 2 in the column **Conditions**, and then, count the number of 2's in the column **Conditions**. The result should look like the table on the right which shows  the number of counts of 2's and the max values. *Preferably without VBA coding*.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What is it that differentiates the first group of 2s from the second group of 2s? Why are they considered separately? i.e. why are you counting three 2s then two 2s? Why not just take the max from all 5?

Also, please edit your post to show what you've tried so far. Thanks

Comment: it's a time series of sales, can't be lumped.

Comment: Ok, so where is the column that indicates the time or sale ID?

Comment: @FlexYourData,,, In condition column 2s are criteria to find Largest for them only, in column Value,, THREE 2s are falling for one of the Largest is 6, and so the others for 7,,, this is what OP is looking for !!

Comment: Right... But what happens when the data are resorted somehow? Or if one of these groups has no 1s? My point is there must be another column somewhere and without it the problem (and any solution) can only be partially stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Using one helper column solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell I2:

  `=COUNTIF($H$2:$H2,H2)`
- Formula in cell J2:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($H$2:$H$10=2)*($I$2:$I$10>=1)*($I$2:$I$10<=3)*($G$2:$G$10)))
  ```
- Formula in cell J3:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($H$2:$H$10=2)*($I$2:$I$10>=4)*($I$2:$I$10<=5)*($G$2:$G$10)))
  ```

---

- Formula in cell K2:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:$I$10>=1)*($I$2:$I$10<=3)*($H$2:$H$10=2))
  ```
- Formula in cell K3:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:$I$10>=4)*($I$2:$I$10<=5)*($H$2:$H$10=2))
  ```

**N.B.**

- *You may replace criteria `2` with cell references, makes the formula dynamic.*
- *For example `(MAX(($H$2:$H$10=$L$1)`, where cell `L1` has criteria `2`, and if required it should be a different value.*
- *For neatness later on you may hide the Helper Column I.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajesh!

Comment: Glad to help you @OliverAmundsen ,, keep asking ☺